# Lock SMS in android

Tags: android, list, broadcastreceiver, android-arrayadapter, android-broadcast

i developing an application where i want to block SMS of some specific numbers.for this purpose i have one an **Activity** and Second is **BroadcastReceiver** class. in **Activity** i have a list where User will enter a number that he want to block. but i don't how will List number will be Access in  **BroadcastReceiver** class to block it. i Access An ArrayAdapter in  **BroadcastReceiver** class but it does not perform to block a call. Any one help me..thanks in advance..
SmsLock.java

```
public class SmsLock extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String phoneNumber;
    String senderNum;

    NumberListActivity ma = new NumberListActivity();

    NumberListActivity num = new NumberListActivity();

    String[] number = new String[] { "+923327765798", "+923219750751",
            "+923445508726" };

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ma.getArrayAdapter();

        // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        try {

            if (bundle != null) {

                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    senderNum = phoneNumber;
                    String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (senderNum.contains(adapter.getItem(i))) {
                        abortBroadcast();
                    }
                }

            } // bundle is null

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" + e);

        }
    }

}
```

NumberListActivity.java

```
public class NumberListActivity extends Activity {
    SharedPreferences preferences1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor1;
    int count1 = 0;
    ListView numList1;
    Button btnAdd1;
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    public static final String Place1 = "placeKey";
    SmsLock brd = new SmsLock();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sms_list);

        preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("Place1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        spEditor1 = preferences1.edit();
        count1 = preferences1.getInt("count1", 0);
        if (count1 > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
                list1.add(preferences1.getString("Value1[" + i + "]", ""));
            }
        }
        final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Item);

        numList1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Smslist);
        btnAdd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);
        numList1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        numList1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*
                 * list.remove(position); //preferences.edit().clear().commit();
                 * preferences.edit().remove("Value["+position+"]").commit();
                 * //count-=1; // adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                 */
                count1 = preferences1.getInt("count1", 0);
                // if (count > 0) {
                for (int i = position; i < count1; i++) {
                    // list.add();
                    if (i < count1)
                        spEditor1.putString(
                                "Value1[" + i + "]",
                                preferences1.getString("Value1[" + (i + 1)
                                        + "]", ""));
                    spEditor1.commit();

                }
                // }
                list1.remove(position);

                count1 -= 1;
                spEditor1.putInt("count1", count1);
                spEditor1.commit();
                // preferences.edit().remove(position);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
        btnAdd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
                spEditor1.putString("Value1[" + count1 + "]", edit.getText()
                        .toString());
                spEditor1.commit();
                list1.add(preferences1.getString("Value1[" + count1 + "]", ""));
                count1 += 1;
                spEditor1.putInt("count1", count1);
                spEditor1.commit();
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }

    public ArrayAdapter<String> getArrayAdapter() {
        return adapter1;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent int1 = new Intent(NumberListActivity.this, Main.class);
        startActivity(int1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the activity, you can enter the number which you can store in the sqlite, and in Broadcast, just like you used array of phone number, instead you need to read phone numbers from the database :)

Comment: you want to block SMS or call?

Comment: @Kedarnath:i uesd that method and result is also ok.. but if user want  to add or delete a number then what he will do...

Comment: Then you need to write a code to save phone number in sqlite.

Comment: @Saqib:SMS And call Both but at this time i want only SMS.

Comment: @Kedarnath: for Storing i used Share Preferences and store successfully.

Comment: That is also a nice option, but when you have multiple phone number like 50,100 then it is better to use sqlite.

Comment: @Kedarnath:Are you have Solution of this issue? i am new and access data form other class is main issue...

Comment: @ZiaUrRehman, not at present, but yes I can write code for this. May be on weekend, not right now.

Comment: have you done enough debugging to know if your if statement is being called? And what you getting from your code of getItem(i) does it match to the one you are performing match to?

Comment: @Saqib:Sir Before this i implement this on Array and SMS Successfully Locked. but here is a issue of ArrayAdapter form Activity Class, i thank..

Comment: that's what I am asking are you sure what you getting from the adapter list item is the same what you matching with?

Comment: @Saqib:i am not sure for adapter list ...but if do this work like String[] number = new String[] { "+923327765798", "+923219750751",
            "+923445508726" }; it block the number

Answer (score 1):

In your broadCast receiver, I assume you have successfully extracted the incoming SMS's phone number and the list of Numbers that are blocked. Then this code is iterating through the list of blocked numbers and entering the if-block, appropriately.

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (senderNum.contains(adapter.getItem(i))) {
                        abortBroadcast();
                    }
                }
```

If you are sure above flow is working fine and still you are not able to block the SMS being received, then one following might be the cause:

1. Priotity: In your manifest file you set a priority for for your application to receive the SMS_RECEIVED intent. Suppose, that your app has a priority 10 and the OS's default SMS app has priority 20, then your app is getting a chance to respond to SMS_RECEIVED intent only after the defaul SMS app. This explains why the abortBroadcast() does not seem to work in above code.

I suggest you set the highest priority possible for your broadCastReceiver in the manifest, so that you get the first chance to handle SMS_RECEIVED intent.

1. From API 19 and above, there can be only one SMS application on a device. If there are 2 or more apps that have a permission to intercept SMS then user has to specify which one of the availaible applications should serve as the defult SMS app. Then the chosen default SMS app will only have the permission to respond to SMS_RECEIVED intent and other applications will not get a chance to receive SMS_RECEIVED intent.

So you also need to set your target SDK to 18 or below to use the SMS interception normally or you need to read some [documentation](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) if you want your app to be compatible with API 19.

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the numbers from which sms you want to block first you need to store all the numbers either in your SQlite database or in preferences so that they can be accessed in broadcast receivers then use

```
 abortBroadcast();
```

to prevent messages to go into inbox.

Comment: abortBroadcast(); may be dangerious because it will prevent broadcasting of SMS_RECEIVED event to all other broadcast receivers